# In Jekyll, how to set default tab size in highlighted code?

Tags: jekyll

The tab size of highlighted code can be set by {% highlight c tabsize=4 %}. But this should be set every code blocks. Is there a method to set the default tab size?

Answer (score 2):

`{% highlight c tabsize=4 %}` is the **only** way to pass arguments to `highlight` tag.

Answer (score 2):

```
# _plugins/pygments_options.rb
class Jekyll::Tags::HighlightBlock
  old_sanitized_opts = instance_method(:sanitized_opts)

  define_method(:sanitized_opts) do |*args|
    old_sanitized_opts.bind(self).(*args).
      merge(Jekyll.configuration.fetch("pygments_options", {}))
  end
end
```

and

```
# _config.yml
# …
pygments_options:
  tabsize: 4
```